# How can I switch to a tag/branch in hg?

Tags: mercurial

I followed the documentation in https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial
and downloaded FF source with:

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ src
```

How can I switch to the FF3.6 'branch' or 'tag'? The documentation said

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-1.9.2/ 192src
```

but I don't want to clone both FF main and FF3.6 twice?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Once you have cloned the repo, you have everything: you can then `hg up branchname` or `hg up tagname` to update your working copy.

UP: `hg up` is a shortcut of `hg update`, which also has `hg checkout` alias for people with `git` habits.

Comment: crazyscot - does one have to clone and checkout? Is it not possible to just grab what you want in 1 step (i.e., `hg clone http://hg.nginx.org/nginx -r "1.4.4"` to checkout version 1.4.4 of the project).

Comment: `hg branch` only lists `default`, but the repo has tags! To list tags, use `hg tags`

Comment: you can use hg clone -u <revision> to update after cloning