# Switching between Mercurial branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

If I look at [Mercurial's site](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NamedBranches), it seems to tell me to use `update -C` to switch between branches. Another [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159623/how-can-i-switch-to-a-tag-branch-in-hg) answer says to use `checkout` instead.

What are the differences? It seems to me that `checkout` updates the files in the working directory to the branch too, like `update -C`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`hg checkout` and `hg update` are aliases for each other, so can be used interchangeably.  From the help for `hg update`:

```
hg update [-c] [-C] [-d DATE] [[-r] REV]

aliases: up, checkout, co

update working directory (or switch revisions)
```

`-C` or `--clean` option is used to throw away uncommitted changes when switching.